# Basics of static and dynamic pressure

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

What actually is static and dynamic pressure? Can they be felt individually? Apart from definitions and equations is there any other way to explain these two quantities?

Answer (score 1):

Static pressure is when no taps are open for example. Dynamic pressure is measured when tap outlets are open.
Static = stationary, Dynamic = moving.

Answer (score 0):

Static Pressure: When the fluid is stationary relative to a body, the pressure exerted on the body by the stationary fluid is termed as Static Pressure.

Dynamic Pressure : When the fluid is in motion, the pressure generated by the flow or movement of the fluid ( excluding it's Static Pressure value) is termed as Dynamic Pressure. It is also expressed as the Kinetic energy per unit volume of the liquid, and also one of the terms of the Bernoulli Equation.

Yes, they can be "felt" i. e. measured individually.

*Total Pressure = Static Pressure + Dynamic Pressure*

Comment: So if we put a manometer in a tube where a fluids is in motion will we measure the static pressure at the boundaries and the dynamic pressure everywhere else?